# serialized generic collections

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have serialized XML file. I am reading the contents which is of type `Dictionary<string,string>` and `List<int>`.

How can I retrieve these 2 objects.
I tried to use ArayList to hold these 2 objects ,but since arraylist is not generic type, it gave exception.Please help..

```
if (fs.Length != 0) 
{ 
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter(); 
    ArrayList dstemp = (ArrayList)bf.Deserialize(fs); 
    // Dictionary<string,string> tempRD = (Dictionary<string,string>) TempList[0]; 
    // List<int> shipto = (List<int>)TempList[1]; 
    this.currentFormData.LinkToShipToList = (List<int>)bf.Deserialize(fs); 
} 
fs.Close();
```

Comment: language please. and some code on what you have done till now

Comment: can you add more info. may be the xml sample.

Comment: @naveen if (fs.Length != 0)
                {
                    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
                    ArrayList dstemp = (ArrayList)bf.Deserialize(fs);
                 //   Dictionary<string,string> tempRD = (Dictionary<string,string>) TempList[0];
                   // List<int> shipto = (List<int>)TempList[1];
                     
                    this.currentFormData.LinkToShipToList = (List<int>)bf.Deserialize(fs);
                }
                fs.Close();

Comment: Surely you deserialise to the type the data was serialised from, what am I missing?

Comment: @Jodrell The sytem receives the file stream which has type Dictionary<string,string> and List<int>.Now if I deserialize to any one type, it gives error.

Comment: I don't understand still. FileStream, Dictionary<string, string> and List<int> are 3 different types. How is this data created?

Comment: Does the object that you receiving was also serialized on the sender side or created by some different technique? Actually I suppose that the 2nd assumption is right because the XML serializer can't serialize Dictionary by default. And could you show the XML file?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just desirialize it as you have serialize it. If you have serialized a Dictionary you can't deserialize a List